# XSLT How to access the value of a matched node in a template

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to be able to access the 'value' of the node I am matching on in my template.

```
 <factfind>
   <myelement>This is a value I want to retreive</myelement>
   ....
   ....
 </factfind>
```

Basically, I want to use the following template (something like it)

```
 <xsl:template name="get-my-element" match="myelement">
   <!-- somehow retreive the value 'This is a value I want to retrieve' -->
   <xsl:value-of select="$this"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

I know I could match a template on `<factfind>` but the problem is I already have a template that is matching that element and handling it in its own way. If I make two templates that handle the one node, only the first one is called.

So you might know the context a bit better, here is how I have it setup atm.

```
 <xsl:template match="loggedin">
   <div id="entities">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="entities"/>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="menuitem"/>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="factfind" />
    </div>
 </xsl:template>
```

The menuitem template would like to make a call-template to the get-my-element template to access the information inside of it, without effecting the behaviour of my factfind template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, the dot expression gives you the context item:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: perfect..! so obvious, too. was kind of a hard thing to search for all my results were 'how to match on the value of a node' etc..